# Why are enums not enforced in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, casting, enumeration

I've boiled down the issue to a few lines of code. Essentially, I am receiving an object and would like to cast it to an interface. However, the enumeration is not enforced when doing the casting. Here is a simplified example showing the enum not being enforced. How do I cast an object to an interface properly?

```
enum Color {
  Blue,
  Green,
  Brown 
}

interface Person {
  eye: Color
}

const myObj: any = {
  eye: 'Orange'
};

const myPerson: Person = myObj;
console.log(myPerson.eye); // Prints 'Orange'
```

Comment: Uh, don't use `any`?

Comment: @Bergi is right. If you just remove the cast to `any` then everything works as you expect. Your code shows a `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Color'` error:  https://tsplay.dev/Nal96w

Answer (score 1):

Typescript does enforce Enums as types. Your example however does not produce the desired effect. By implying that `myObj` is of type `any` no types are enforced.

```
enum Status {
    ONLINE,
    OFFLINE,
    ERROR
}

status: Status = "Active";
```

This will give the following Typescript error:
`TS2322: Type '"Active"' is not assignable to type 'Status'.`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve you can do using a `Type`instead of an `Interface`

```
type Color  = 'Blue' | 'Green' | 'Brown';

interface Person {
    eye: Color
}

const myObj: Person = { // Use the interface instead of any
    eye: 'Orange'
};

const myPerson: Person = myObj;
console.log(myPerson.eye);
```

Then you will get an type error when using another than the specified Color

[image]

Going the `Interface` way you will have numeric mappings and must assign like in this example:

```
enum Color {
    Blue,
    Green,
    Brown
}

interface Person {
    eye: Color
}

const myObj: Person = {
    eye: Color.Blue // Here the value is 0 then
};

const myPerson: Person = myObj;
console.log(myPerson.eye); // Prints 0
```

Comment: `const myObj = {
    eye: 'Orange'
};` also has the desired effect and still implements the interface while improving brevity and increasing the odds that errors will be picked up by the compiler

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `any` type in `myObj`.

As it is in the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), the `any` "convince TypeScript that a particular line of code is okay."